# Unable to upload files to Artifactory using JFrog CLI

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm getting following error when I upload files to an empty repository. Please help me to resolve it.

```
[Error] [Thread 0] Artifactory response: 404
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "message": "Checksum deploy failed. No existing file with SHA-1: d8fdf6980d79e6e3966d44662c5d1b2d2fa37ec2"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Empty files are uploading successfully & from UI I was able to upload

Comment: What is the CLI command your are running?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm using following command .  jfrog rt u "./test.txt" my-local-repo/test/

Comment: Interestingly upload is working fine from my laptop using same command. But from one of the cloud server it is not working for size more than 1KB. I'm suspecting some network restriction

Comment: Are you getting the 404 response only when trying to upload from the cloud server?

Comment: Yes...We are using site to site VPN tunnel which has private ip but some reason it is not allowing files size more than 4kb.  I patched artifactory server with public ip , it worked.

Comment: Please make sure that the following headers are allowed to pass though your VPN tunnel: "X-Checksum-Deploy", "X-Checksum-Sha1" and "X-Checksum-Md5".